# Why is a protocol hiding methods and properties from the super class?

Tags: ios, class, cocoa, cocoa-touch

Consider this class: `CAEmitterLayer`. This class responds to the property `name`.

Now I have created a `CAEmitterLayer` called `MyEmitter` and this class conforms to a protocol I have created called `MyProtocol`.

`MyEmitter` class declaration is like this:

**HEADER**

```
#import "MyProtocol.h"

@interface MyEmitter : CAEmitterLayer <MyProtocol>

@end
```

**IMPLEMENTATION**

```
#import "MyEmitter.h"

@implementation MyEmitter

@synthesize internalString = _internalString;

@end
```

and the protocol is just this:

```
@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * internalString;

@end
```

This is the problem. If I create a new object like this

```
MyEmitter *obj = [[MyEmitter alloc] init];
```

and try to use the `name` property, xcode complains with **no known instance method for selector 'name'**

In fact I cannot access any property from the class `CAEmitterLayer` even `MyEmitter` being a subclass of that class.

I am trying to use it like this:

```
  for (id <MyProtocol> node in nodes) {
    [node setName:@"ddd"]; // error here
  }
```

Apparently the protocol is hiding everything from the super class. Why is that and how do I solve?

NOTE: I had to add that synthesize line to the class, or xcode would not stop complaining.

Comment: Show how you're trying to use it, is it actually using `obj` from your code line there? Can you access `internalString` without an error? And yes, protocol properties always need to be synthesised (or redefined).

Comment: added to the question.... yes I can access internalString.

Comment: I cannot access any property of CAEmitterLayer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The static type of `node` is `id <MyProtocol>`. The compiler rightfully says that this type doesn't declare a `setName:` method.

Just switch to `MyEmitter *` and it should work.

Comment: Why, of course. That's what static type safety is all about.

Answer (score 2):

To expand upon the other answer, you are receiving a *compile time* error because the compiler has to work from what you have told it.

Now, you know (or at least hope) that `node` is going to be an instance of `MyEmitter` at run-time, but the compiler doesn't because you have told it that `node` is an `id <MyProtocol>`.

If you could get your program to run anyway then `[node setName:]` would work because objective-C finds the right selector at run time.

Similarly if you told the compiler that `node` was an instance of `MyEmitter` but at run time it was a different object class (due to an error somewhere else in your code) then it would compile but potentially throw an exception at run time.

So you could say -

```
 for (MyEmitter *node in nodes) {
    [node setName:@"ddd"]; 
 }
```

Or, if you don't need to do anything that is specific to your subclass you could even say

```
 for (CAEmitterLayer *node in nodes) {
    [node setName:@"ddd"]; 
 }
```